# How to dynamically change navigation bar item's logo in Java class?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am integrating Google and Facebook to my application, i.e. I have 2 ways to login in the login page. I have a navigation drawer in the main activity. In the drawer, I have a logout item. I want to be able to set the  icon to Google icon or Facebook icon depending on the login method user choose.

For example, if the user logged in with Facebook, the icon of logout button will be a Facebook icon.

Is there a way to somehow set the icon in main activity class? Like

```
if (loggedInWithFB)
    findViewById(R.id.icon).setImage(fbicon);
else
    findViewById(R.id.icon).setImage(googleicon);
```

Comment: Navigation Bar and NavigationView is different, you mentioned in your question as Navigation Bar.

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon_white);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this icon com_facebook_button_icon_white is not exist any more in the new Facebook plugin. What is the replacement please ?